# Replace not working for multiple strings replacement when each row is a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a function which replaces `http`, `https`, `com` and `www` from my dataframe.

**df**

```
content                                                       Col2  Col3   Col4
[www,roger, that,com, http, great, hi, www]                   89     78     40
[http, https,www,roger, http, for,com, http, you, bye, www]   93     94     30
and so one...there are 30,000 rows
```

Not that each row is a list in my dataset for column content

**Defining Function**

```
def replace(df):
    for row in df:
        for index, item in enumerate(row):
            # create string *and update row*
            row[index] = item.replace("www", " ")
            row[index] = item.replace("http", " ")
            row[index] = item.replace("https", " ")
            row[index] = item.replace("com", " ")
    return df
```

**Calling function**

```
df['content']=replace(df['content'])
```

The problem is that www gets replaced, but http, https and com do not get replaced. What is it that im doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple list comprehension on the column:

```
rep = ['http', 'https', 'www', 'com']
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in rep])

                                            col1                      col2
0  [www, roger, that, com, http, great, hi, www]  [roger, that, great, hi]
1                 [http, https, www, roger, for]              [roger, for]
```

**Sample Data**

```
cl=[["www","roger", "that","com", "http", "great", "hi", "www"],
    ["http", "https", "www","roger","for"]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': cl})
```